# Change element of dictionary with values as list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary similar to this

```
x ={'1': [['a','b'],['ac','d']], '2' : [['p','qa'],['r','s']]}
```

And I would like to access the individual strings i.e. a,b etc , compare if it has "a" in it, delete those.

The main question is - how do I access the strings? How do I change it?

I tried using nested loops, but was unable to change, as I guess assignment stmts do not work that way.

Any idea how to proceed with such situation?

Edit : The naive approach I used -

```
for item in x:
    for ele in x[item]:
        for i in ele:
             i = #assign new value here using regex comparison
```

But when I try to print x after this, it stays same.
Obviously. assignment statements do not work this way. Any idea about how should I access the elements to change it?

Comment: Delete the string from the list, delete the list, or delete the key and value?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You are much more likely to get an answer for your question if you include your input, your desired output, what code you have tried and any output you receive including the full text of any error messages.

Comment: `x = {k: [[val for val in sublist if 'a' not in val] for sublist in v] for k, v in x.items()}`  (Note that this does not mutate your original dictionary.  It creates a brand new dictionary with new lists.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x ={'1': [['a','b'],['ac','d']], '2' : [['p','qa'],['r','s']]}
>>> for key in x:
...     for n, item in enumerate(x[key]):
...             x[key][n] = list(filter(lambda l: 'a' not in l, x[key][n]))
...
>>> x
{'2': [['p'], ['r', 's']], '1': [['b'], ['d']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example,

```
for item in x:
    for ele in x[item]:
        for i in ele:
            i = #assign new value here using regex comparison
```

`i` is a copy of the string in `ele`, so assigning to it has no effect on the original. You need to modify the list `ele`. Possibly, `ele[ele.index(i)] = #whatever`. Note, however, that this will not work correctly if you have identical values in the list. It will only change the first one.

Not sure what you're actually trying to do, but it may be easier to use a list comprehension, at least for the innermost list. This will allow you to change each element of the innermost list. Perhaps,

```
for item in x.values():
    for ele in item:
        ele[:] = [#whatever for i in ele]
```

where `ele[:]` is needed to change the original inner list (just `ele` won't work), and I used the more Pythonic `x.values()` when we actually wanted the values, not the keys.